# Rearranging a flat Array to a nested Array

Tags: javascript

I have data that looks as follows:

```
[
   {
      "Type1":[
         {
            "ID":2,
            "DATE":"2017-08-08",
            "SENDER":3,
         },
         {
            "ID":1,
            "DATE":"2017-07-07",
            "SENDER":2,
         },
         {
            "ID":1,
            "DATE":"2017-06-07",
            "SENDER":3,
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I am trying to get it so each ID has its own node so that I can loop through each ID and then loop through its associated dates/sender data in Vue. However, I am struggling with map of how to do this. The data is too flat for looping through as I need to loop through ID then its associated items. So far this is what I have using reduce but this still does not create the expected result and is object rather than an array of objects like my original result:

```
                        this.TimelineV2 = this.timelineArr['Type1'].reduce(function (r, a) {
                            r[a.ID] = r[a.ID] || [];
                            r[a.ID].push(a);
                            return r;
```

I have found examples of making arrays flat but the opposite is difficult to find examples as there is so many shapes of arrays to get a good example of what I want:

```
[
   {
      "Type1":[
         {
            "ID":2,
            "DETAILS":[{
                "DATE":"2017-08-08",
                "SENDER":3,
            }]
         },
         {
            "ID":1,
            "DETAILS":[{
                "DATE":"2017-07-07",
                "SENDER":2,
            },
            {
                "DATE":"2017-06-07",
                "SENDER":3,
            },
            ]
         }
      ]
    }
]
```

Comment: u can instead `r[a.ID] = r[a.ID] || {ID:a.ID,DETAILS:[]}` and `r[a.ID].DETAILS.push({DATE:a.DATE,SENDER:a.SENDER});` and wrap the whole thing in Object.values(...)

Comment: Can you write this as an answer with it fully written out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a little modification to your implementation. You can use an object as an accumulator to group by the ID and finally take the values array of the object. You can use rest syntax to support multiple fields

```js
const Type1 =  [{
      "ID": 2,
      "DATE": "2017-08-08",
      "SENDER": 3,
    },
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "DATE": "2017-07-07",
      "SENDER": 2,
    },
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "DATE": "2017-06-07",
      "SENDER": 3,
    }
  ]


const res = Object.values(Type1.reduce(function (r, {ID,...rest}) {
  r[ID] = r[ID] || {ID,DETAILS:[]};
  r[ID].DETAILS.push({...rest});
  return r
}, {}));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) every element in the input to an output object of the structure `{ Type1: <some value here>}`. Then to get the value to put there first group by `ID` using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (and the [nullish coalescing assignment operator `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)) and then use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) together with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the desired structure of the output.

```js
const input = [{
  "Type1": [{
      "ID": 2,
      "DATE": "2017-08-08",
      "SENDER": 3,
    },
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "DATE": "2017-07-07",
      "SENDER": 2,
    },
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "DATE": "2017-06-07",
      "SENDER": 3,
    }
  ]
}];


const test = input.map(x => {
  const groupedById = x.Type1.reduce((acc, { ID, ...rest }) => ((acc[ID] ??= []).push({ ...rest }), acc), {});
  return {
    Type1: Object.entries(groupedById).map(([id, details]) => ({
      ID: id,
      DETAILS: details
    }))
  };
});


console.log(test);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
    top: 0;
}
```

> Obviously the code could be written shorter, but for clarity I kept it like this.

Comment: What if you have more than the DATE AND SENDER fields? Is there a shortcut to importing all the fields using ...?

Comment: @IrishRedneck yes instead of `(acc, cur)` u can use rest syntax `(acc, {ID,...rest})` then `(acc[ID] ??= []).push({...rest})`

Comment: yes, @cmgchess is right you can use the spread operator to avoid having to manually assign the properties. I've adjusted the answer accordingly.